# How do i do to invert object tracking orientation

Tags: objects, video, tracking

Here is the situation, im practicing a bit using footage from http://www.hollywoodcamerawork.com/trackingplates.html

The problem is that even it has an error of 1.4 after solving the movement its okish however its facing in the other direction, as you can se the tracking its on the girls face but in the camera its like it was looking from behind, so the Z of the protection its in the other direction, is there a way to flip the result without duplicating cameras or a weird hack?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Try to get a Solve Error of 0.6 or lower

They don't provide any camera information and especially the *Focal Length* is missing, so you'll need trying out what works.

#### 1. Find as much points as possible in the face to track

[image]

#### 2. Tracking Settings

Have a look in the *Tracking Settings* to figure out what works best.
In this case the **Fast Motion** preset works really fine:

[image]

You can also change the Tracking Speed in the Extra Settings to switch from *Fastest* to *Realtime*:

[image]

*This helps during the tracking process to see when a tracker looses the point.*

#### 3. Refine and Cleap up

I figuered out that refining leads to an incorrect lens distortion in this case. Also there is no need to refine K1 and K2.

Find Tracks with a high *Average Error* and remove bad tracks for a solid solution:

[image]

At the end this should lead in a robust solution.
I was able to get a *Solve Error* of 0.57 and all the tracker are well positioned in 3D space:

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Good read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42332/19287)

Comment: in your file, you are camera tracking the scene, i did that to get camera info from the survey shot, 
In this case im doing object tracking(not camera tracking) using the info of the camera that i get from the survey shot

Comment: It depends on what do you want to achieve, but in genral it doesnt matter wether the camera or the object moves.

Comment: the objective was to practice basically object tracking, i did plenty camera tracking but never tried to track objects.

Comment: edited the answer. Again as you can see it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, the result of the camera track works in this case, but that was not the point, the point was to object track, this is not a work or homework that i need to present to someone.
the point here was to test "object tracking" that particular function, not about how to get to a result in some other way but how does that tool work, and if it has a possibility to tell the object track, ok this is backwards, or how to control it.
The idea wasn't to do a camera track, although that yes it will work as an isolated posibility in this case.
By the way, the lights needs to be parented to the camera

Comment: Add an object. Copy paste the trackers to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the camera inverted solver is to set the scale with -1 value of 2 trackers...[image]